# Entity Framework 6 - Timing queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and it's awesome database interceptor features to log queries which are being sent from application the database. However, I am struggling to time those queries, I have a long running query which returns hundred of thousands to millions of rows so it takes around 6 to 15 seconds depending on the amount of data this query is going to return. Entity framework is returning a SqlDataReader because of which I cannot get the exact time it takes to get the result. I want to know the complete execution time from the time query was sent to the time last row was read. Is there a way I can do it.

Comment: If you want to see how long the SQL is running, you can use Profiler.

Comment: To add on to the SQL Server Profiler tool suggestion, the reported duration will reflect the time the request was received by SQL Server until the last TDS buffer was filled by the server.  SQL Server cannot measure the network latency of the initial request or receipt of the final response, just the time with the database engine.  Probably not an issue with a large result set like yours but this latency may be the lion's share of the end-to-end response time a small query that returns a single buffer of results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I want to log some meta data along with the query like who was the user that triggered this query, and bunch of other meta data which lives on the web server. Is it even possible to do this from the web server layer?

Comment: Wrap the call in a trace logger. If it takes longer than a certain time, log the passed metadata and anything else you want.

Comment: What do you mean by wrap in a trace logger?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is the logger I usually use for EF.

```
public class EFLoggerForTesting : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<DbCommand, DateTime> m_StartTime = new ConcurrentDictionary<DbCommand, DateTime>();

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        Log(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        Log(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        Log(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    private static void Log<T>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<T> interceptionContext)
    {
        DateTime startTime;
        TimeSpan duration;


        if (m_StartTime.TryRemove(command, out startTime))
        {
            duration = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        }
        else
            duration = TimeSpan.Zero;

        var requestId =-1;
        string message;

        var parameters = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DbParameter param in command.Parameters)
        {
            parameters.AppendLine(param.ParameterName + " " + param.DbType + " = " + param.Value);
        }

        if (interceptionContext.Exception == null)
        {
            message = string.Format("Database call took {0} sec. RequestId {1} \r\nCommand:\r\n{2}", duration.TotalSeconds.ToString("N3"), requestId, parameters.ToString() + command.CommandText);
        }
        else
        {
            message = string.Format("EF Database call failed after {0} sec. RequestId {1} \r\nCommand:\r\n{2}\r\nError:{3} ", duration.TotalSeconds.ToString("N3"), requestId, parameters.ToString() + command.CommandText, interceptionContext.Exception);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }


    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        OnStart(command);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        OnStart(command);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        OnStart(command);
    }
    private static void OnStart(DbCommand command)
    {
        m_StartTime.TryAdd(command, DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the documentation is non-existent so I don't know if this will work for your scenario.

Comment: Although this wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for this should provide others enough information to get their work started.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen What do you use requestId for?

Comment: Correlating website calls to database calls. Lets say someone hits the //myapp.com//user/23 page. I generate a new request id, say 107, and use it for every database call. Then if I see request 107 makes 15 database calls to the user table, I know something is screwed up. (Yes, that's a real example. EF makes it way too easy to invoke the database without thinking about it.)

Comment: P.S. My sample above is missing the code that reads from the HttpContext.Current to get the real request id. The -1 is a placeholder for database calls that aren't tied to a web request.

Comment: I was looking for maximum accuracy on timing the performance of the queries and tried implementing what you have here. It turned out that it often disagreed strongly with the performance listed in `dbContext.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m)`. After removing your odd pass of non-existing start-times, I still found that at odd times, the startTime and DateTime.UtcNow was exactly the same tick. That seems impossible for me, especially considering the tested database is stored in the local network, at another machine than EntityFramework is hosted on.

Comment: That is indeed strange. But since the interface isn't properly documented, I don't know where to start looking for a cause.

Comment: I asked elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40339358/1380710. The odd timing is because `DateTime` isn't guaranteed to have accuracy above the system timer, which for Windows NT is 10ms, and for Windows 8+ is 1ms. I had to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for higher precision.

Comment: This code shows the same requests multiple times and time is not correct in this case.

Comment: @kemsky Care to explain further?

Comment: Interceptor methods are called multiple times for the same query, you can check it yourself using debugger.

Comment: Um, I'm counting on Interceptor methods being called multiple times. Specifically, one time when it starts and one time when it finishes. If you are seeing something else you need to be more specific.

Comment: The above methods needs to be overidden to make the code functional.

Comment: Rather than `startTime != default(DateTime)` can't you just check the boolean result of `m_StartTime.TryRemove(command, out startTime)`?

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in a web application, you can try Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/. Otherwise, try MiniProfiler: http://miniprofiler.com/.

Comment: I don't want to track the full cycle. I just want to know information about the Entity framework part.

Comment: Idea here is go learn and do it myself rather than use already baked solutions

Answer (score 3):

You can try [the example explained here](http://b2ben.blogspot.com/2014/09/sql-query-performance-monitoring-with.html)

In this example, we are starting a `Stopwatch` when a command starts executing and we stop the `Stopwatch` when the command is completed, this way we can identify the slow queries and log them.

```
public class SqlMonitorInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly int sqlWarningThresholdMs = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlPerformance_warningThresholdMilliseconds"]);
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuting();
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuting();
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuting();
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        CommandExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    private void CommandExecuting() {
        _stopwatch.Restart();
    }

    private void CommandExecuted<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext);
        LogIfTooSlow(command, _stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private void LogIfError<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("Command {0} failed with exception {1}",
                command.CommandText, interceptionContext.Exception);
        }
    }

    private void LogIfTooSlow(DbCommand command, TimeSpan completionTime)
    {
        if (completionTime.TotalMilliseconds > sqlWarningThresholdMs)
        {
            logger.WarnFormat("Query time ({0}ms) exceeded the threshold of {1}ms. Command: \"{2}\"",
                completionTime.TotalMilliseconds, sqlWarningThresholdMs, command.CommandText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Ricardo Peres answer suggests, Glimpse is good for this. It comes with the `Glimpse.Ado` plugin that can be used to easily profile any `DbConnection`, which is the main class to extend here.

The manual integration point for ADO in Glimpse is to wrap the `DbConnection` in a `GlimpseDbConnection`, as can be seen in this blog post: http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration. Other providers like EF are automatically integrated with the `Glimpse.Ef` package.

If you still decide you want to achieve this manually, I would suggest wrapping `DbConneciton` yourself and using this in-place of the regular `DbConnection`. You could get simple timings doing this.

You can see how Glimpse do it on their github: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/tree/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType

Alternatively, there is always the option to add this sort of logging at the repository level or at the method level depending on how much logging you *need*.

Answer (score 2):

EF Core version of Johnathan's accepted answer, for anyone searching:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;
```

```cs
public class EFLogger: DbCommandInterceptor
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DateTime> _startTimes = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DateTime>();

    public override DbDataReader ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader reader)
    {
        Log(command, eventData);
        return reader;
    }

    public override int NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result)
    {
        Log(command, eventData);
        return result;
    }

    public override object ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, object result)
    {
        Log(command, eventData);
        return result;
    }

    public override void CommandFailed(DbCommand command, CommandErrorEventData eventData)
    {
        Log(command, eventData);
    }

    private static void Log(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData)
    {
        TimeSpan? duration = null;
        if (_startTimes.TryRemove(eventData.CommandId, out DateTime startTime))
            duration = DateTime.Now - startTime;

        var parameters = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DbParameter param in command.Parameters)
        {
            parameters.AppendLine(param.ParameterName + " " + param.DbType + " = " + param.Value);
        }

        string message = $"Database call {(eventData is CommandErrorEventData ? "FAILED" : "succeeded")} in {duration?.TotalMilliseconds ?? -1:N3} ms. CommandId {eventData.CommandId} \r\nCommand:\r\n{parameters}{command.CommandText}";
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        OnStart(eventData.CommandId);
        return result;
    }
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        OnStart(eventData.CommandId);
        return result;
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result)
    {
        OnStart(eventData.CommandId);
        return result;
    }

    private void OnStart(Guid commandId)
    {
        _startTimes.TryAdd(commandId, DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my simplified version of the original [`DatabaseLogFormatter`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Interception/DatabaseLogFormatter.cs). The main difference is that there is no filtering in this one and I don't log the actual SQL query or it's parameters (since I'm only interested in timing the queries). It log when it has opened a connection, executed a query and when it closed the connection again. As @aske-b [noticed above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196944/entity-framework-6-timing-queries/48744065#comment67797738_27365855) using `DateTime` (as the accepted answer does) just isn't very accurate.

---

```
public class CustomDatabaseLogFormatter : IDbCommandInterceptor, IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    private readonly Action<string> _writeAction;
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a formatter that will log every command from any context and also commands that do not originate from a context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This constructor is not used when a delegate is set on <see cref="Database.Log" />. Instead it can be
    /// used by setting the formatter directly using <see cref="DbInterception.Add" />.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="writeAction">The delegate to which output will be sent.</param>
    public CustomDatabaseLogFormatter(Action<string> writeAction)
    {
        Check.NotNull(writeAction, "writeAction");

        _writeAction = writeAction;
    }

    internal Action<string> WriteAction
    {
        get { return _writeAction; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the given string to the underlying write delegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="output">The string to write.</param>
    protected virtual void Write(string output)
    {
        _writeAction(output);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The stopwatch used to time executions. This stopwatch is started at the end of
    /// <see cref="NonQueryExecuting" />, <see cref="ScalarExecuting" />, and <see cref="ReaderExecuting" />
    /// methods and is stopped at the beginning of the <see cref="NonQueryExecuted" />, <see cref="ScalarExecuted" />,
    /// and <see cref="ReaderExecuted" /> methods. If these methods are overridden and the stopwatch is being used
    /// then the overrides should either call the base method or start/stop the stopwatch themselves.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The stopwatch.</returns>
    protected internal Stopwatch Stopwatch
    {
        get { return _stopwatch; }
    }

    private void RestartStopwatch()
    {
        Stopwatch.Restart();
    }

    private void StopStopwatch()
    {
        Stopwatch.Stop();
    }

    #region IDbCommandInterceptor
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called before a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery" /> or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Starts the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        RestartStopwatch();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called after a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery" /> or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Stops the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/> and calls <see cref="Executed" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        StopStopwatch();
        Executed(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called before a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)" /> or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Starts the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        RestartStopwatch();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called after a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)" /> or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Stops the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/> and calls <see cref="Executed" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        StopStopwatch();
        Executed(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called before a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteScalar" />  or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Starts the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        RestartStopwatch();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called after a call to <see cref="DbCommand.ExecuteScalar" />  or
    /// one of its async counterparts is made.
    /// Stops the stopwatch returned from <see cref="Stopwatch"/> and calls
    /// <see cref="Executed" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public virtual void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        StopStopwatch();
        Executed(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called whenever a command has completed executing. Calls <see cref="LogResult" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the operation's results.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="command">The command that was executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the command.</param>
    public virtual void Executed<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        LogResult(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to log the result of executing a command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the operation's results.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="command">The command being logged.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the command.</param>
    public virtual void LogResult<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(command, "command");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch;

        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
        {
            Write(
                String.Format(StringResources.CommandLogFailed, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, interceptionContext.Exception.Message)
                );
        }
        else if (interceptionContext.TaskStatus.HasFlag(TaskStatus.Canceled))
        {
            Write(String.Format(StringResources.CommandLogCanceled, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }
        else
        {
            var result = interceptionContext.Result;
            var resultString = (object)result == null
                ? "null"
                : (result is DbDataReader)
                    ? result.GetType().Name
                    : result.ToString();
            Write(String.Format(StringResources.CommandLogComplete, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, resultString));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDbConnectionInterceptor
    public void BeginningTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void BeganTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void Closing(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after <see cref="DbConnection.Close" /> is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The connection that was closed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public void Closed(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(connection, "connection");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
        {
            Write(String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionCloseErrorLog, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, interceptionContext.Exception.Message));
        }
        else
        {
            Write(String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionClosedLog, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow));
        }
    }

    public void ConnectionStringGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ConnectionStringGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ConnectionStringSetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ConnectionStringSet(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ConnectionTimeoutGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ConnectionTimeoutGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void DatabaseGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void DatabaseGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void DataSourceGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void DataSourceGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void Disposing(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void Disposed(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void EnlistingTransaction(DbConnection connection, EnlistTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void EnlistedTransaction(DbConnection connection, EnlistTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void Opening(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after <see cref="DbConnection.Open" /> or its async counterpart is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The connection that was opened.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    public void Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        Check.NotNull(connection, "connection");
        Check.NotNull(interceptionContext, "interceptionContext");

        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
        {
            Write(
                interceptionContext.IsAsync
                    ? String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionOpenErrorLogAsync,
                        DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, interceptionContext.Exception.Message)
                    : String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionOpenErrorLog, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, interceptionContext.Exception.Message));
        }
        else if (interceptionContext.TaskStatus.HasFlag(TaskStatus.Canceled))
        {
            Write(String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionOpenCanceledLog, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow));
        }
        else
        {
            Write(
                interceptionContext.IsAsync
                    ? String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionOpenedLogAsync, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                    : String.Format(StringResources.ConnectionOpenedLog, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow));
        }
    }

    public void ServerVersionGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void ServerVersionGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<string> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void StateGetting(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<ConnectionState> interceptionContext)
    { }

    public void StateGot(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext<ConnectionState> interceptionContext)
    { } 
    #endregion
}
```

---

```
internal class Check
{
    public static T NotNull<T>(T value, string parameterName)
        where T : class
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

---

```
StringResources.resx:
CommandLogCanceled          Canceled in {0} ms{1}
CommandLogComplete          Completed in {0} ms with result: {1}
CommandLogFailed            Failed in {0} ms with error: {1}
ConnectionClosedLog         Closed connection at {0}
ConnectionCloseErrorLog     Failed to close connection at {0} with error: {1}
ConnectionOpenCanceledLog   Cancelled open connection at {0}
ConnectionOpenedLog         Opened connection at {0}
ConnectionOpenedLogAsync    Opened connection asynchronously at {0}
ConnectionOpenErrorLog      Failed to open connection at {0} with error: {1}
ConnectionOpenErrorLogAsync Failed to open connection asynchronously at {0} with error: {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather simplistic, but couldn't you use a System.Timers.Timer object? Call start just before the EF code and call end just after the EF code. If you have async code in there you could call .Result and remove the awaits in order to run the code synchronously and time the calls. In addition to this if you use the SQL profiler and subtract one value from the other (Timer - Profiler) you will get an idea of how long the EF code is taking to execute.

Comment: I was hoping for a centralized solution and not having to do something over and over again each time I use Entity framework anywhere.

Comment: I guess you could create some sort of wrapper for every call to entity framework but I think the complexity of what you are trying to achieve definitely outweighs the benefits. My preferred approach would be to time where necessary and make improvements during development and put live code without timers etc. In the particular case of your long running 5+ second query I would try and put that into an optimized stored procedure and see if that would bring the time down.

Comment: @MaxRev17 Well, it seems somewhat simple to do in a general way according to the answer by Jonathan Allen...

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution here is to measure queries from some higher level - from DAL method level. So **you can mark each db/dal method by custom attribute**, that will collect information about method execution time and do what you want (logging).

For example, you can use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) lib and [Fody's MethodTimer](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer) extension for it.

Few sentences **how to** :

For example, you have repository `UsersRepositry` with method "GetAll" :

```
//semi-pseudo code
public class UsersRepository {
   ...
   public async Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync(){
      return await _efDbContext.Users.AllAsync();
   }   
}
```

using Fody you can mark it by `[Time]` attribute :

```
[Time]
public async Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync(){
      return await _efDbContext.Users.AllAsync();
}
```

And adding static logger, log execution time :

```
public static class MethodTimeLogger
    {
        public static void Log(MethodBase methodBase, TimeSpan elapsed, string message)
        {
            //Do some logging here, for example : 
            YourLogger.Info($"{methodBase.DeclaringType.Name}.{methodBase.Name} : {elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
        }
    }
```

**How it works :**

Fody will re-write in time of compilation on IL level your marked method to :

```
public class UsersRepository 
{
    public async Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            //Some code u are curious how long it takes
            return await _efDbContext.Users.AllAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            MethodTimeLogger.Log(methodof(GetAllAsync), stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

**Conclusion :**
A good way to measure execution time of your DAL methods. You can't log some internal DbCommand info here (such sql query) or raw execution time without mapping entities, but in general - depends of your needs. In my case it was enough just to log method/execution time.

Hope, it will help someone. Have a good coding!