# EF6 DbContext.Database.Log duration differs from SQL Server Profiler duration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-profiler

The duration time for EF queries logged by `DbContext.Database.Log` differs from the actual duration time that I can see in SQL Server Profiler.

In SQL Server Profile I see a line looking something like this

```
EventClass       TextData                          Duration 
RPC:Completed    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT...    59473
```

But nowhere in the `DbContext.Database.Log`s can I find a query with that duration time. Accoring to those logs, no query took more than a couple of ms.

I've also tried to implement a custom `IDbCommandInterceptor` that intercepts, times and logs EF queries manually (something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365855/492067), but I get the same problem there.

What am I missing? Is it something with the actual reading of the data as well?

The EF query in question looks like this:

```
var duplicates = databaseItems.Where(item => newItems.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure that the line you are referring from sql server profiler originates from the dbcontext and not from some other source?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Pretty sure yeah. I've looked through all the trace logs for the entire lifetime of the application. There is nothing in the logs coming even close to the ~60 seconds duration i see in SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: How many items in your newsItems collection ? depending on its size, compilation and query plan generation can be horribly slow, will occur on each call.Not sure compilation time appears in DbContext.Database.Log

Comment: @jbl `newItems` is < 100. Those are the new items I will eventually insert. `databaseItems` is ~ 50 000.

Comment: How much is the timeout? It could be that SqlClient raises an Exception (so no logs or no log entry you are looking for) but SQL Server continue to work.